# Multicolumn layout

Tags: tables

I'm currently facing an issue with a table I'm trying to make that has many multicolumns and many rows. The following is how I have it now:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrrr}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Count} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Median} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Max} \\
\cmidrule(l{5pt}r{5pt}){2-3}\cmidrule(l{5pt}r{5pt}){4-5}\cmidrule(l{5pt}r{5pt}){6-7}\cmidrule(l{5pt}r{5pt}){8-9}\cmidrule(l{5pt}r{5pt}){10-11}\cmidrule(l{5pt}r{5pt}){12-13}           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sample 2} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Group 1}} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Var 1} & 0.07  & 0.25  & 0.55  & 0.39  & 0.27  & 0.46  & 0.81  & 0.99  & 0.46  & 0.91  & 0.85  & 0.5 \\
    Var 2 & 0.49  & 0.74  & 0.79  & 0.11  & 0.23  & 0.34  & 0.22  & 0.37  & 0.08  & 0.14  & 0.58  & 0.64 \\
    Var 3 & 0.79  & 0.19  & 0.88  & 0.7   & 0.46  & 0.76  & 0.86  & 0.84  & 0.87  & 0.07  & 0.65  & 0.92 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Group 2}} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    Var 4 & 0.52  & 0.91  & 0.68  & 0.17  & 0.44  & 0.77  & 0.85  & 0.54  & 0.51  & 0.38  & 0.29  & 0.1 \\
    Var 5 & 0.05  & 0.14  & 0.87  & 0.64  & 0.33  & 0.58  & 0.18  & 0.78  & 0.8   & 0.68  & 0.92  & 0.57 \\
    Var 6 & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.61  & 0.42  & 0.25  & 0.54  & 0.68  & 0.7   & 0.34  & 0.11  & 0.49  & 0.11 \\
    Var 7 & 0.32  & 0.08  & 0.98  & 0.52  & 0.82  & 0.62  & 0.22  & 0.95  & 0.21  & 0.36  & 0.73  & 0.55 \\
    Var 8 & 0.63  & 0.58  & 0.86  & 0.39  & 0.81  & 0.79  & 0.19  & 0.89  & 0.12  & 0.7   & 0.32  & 0.25 \\
    Var 9 & 0.32  & 0.28  & 0.83  & 0.45  & 0.62  & 0.76  & 0.04  & 0.88  & 0.94  & 0.57  & 0.47  & 0.97 \\
    Var 10 & 0.71  & 0.65  & 0.78  & 0.69  & 0.47  & 0.89  & 0.5   & 0.68  & 0.8   & 0.38  & 0.62  & 0.71 \\
    Var 11 & 0.14  & 0.7   & 0.51  & 0.77  & 0.6   & 0.54  & 0.6   & 0.93  & 0.47  & 0.05  & 0.23  & 0.87 \\
    Var 12 & 0.33  & 0.02  & 0.4   & 0.39  & 0.35  & 0.65  & 0.03  & 0.45  & 0.77  & 0.59  & 0.61  & 0.6 \\
    Var 13 & 0.7   & 0.13  & 0.39  & 0.51  & 0.68  & 0.74  & 0.65  & 0.59  & 0.4   & 0.21  & 0.26  & 0.08 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Group 2}} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    Var 14 & 0     & 0.15  & 0.55  & 0.96  & 0.59  & 0.6   & 0.54  & 0.81  & 0.49  & 0.6   & 0.79  & 0.5 \\
    Var 15 & 0.65  & 0.35  & 0.62  & 0.18  & 0.93  & 0.37  & 0.39  & 0.42  & 0.78  & 0.1   & 0.66  & 0.78 \\
    Var 16 & 0.64  & 0.43  & 0.07  & 0.36  & 0.91  & 0.18  & 0.41  & 0.59  & 0.18  & 1     & 0.85  & 0.25 \\
    Var 17 & 0.03  & 0.57  & 0.53  & 0.67  & 0.13  & 0.68  & 0.48  & 0.01  & 0.75  & 0.18  & 0.85  & 0.96 \\
    Var 18 & 0.12  & 0.72  & 0.61  & 0.1   & 0.61  & 0.66  & 0.65  & 0.37  & 0.42  & 0.8   & 0.4   & 0.46 \\
    Var 19 & 0.14  & 0.39  & 0.84  & 0.61  & 0.83  & 0.09  & 0.15  & 0.2   & 0.7   & 0.44  & 0.2   & 0.57 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Group 2}} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    Var 20 & 0.7   & 0.05  & 0.94  & 0.94  & 0.7   & 0.21  & 0.01  & 0.06  & 0.44  & 0.99  & 0.71  & 0.86 \\
    Var 21 & 0.49  & 0.64  & 0.51  & 0.74  & 0.37  & 0.58  & 0.55  & 0.22  & 0.61  & 0.04  & 0.68  & 0.91 \\
    Var 22 & 0.83  & 0.37  & 0.67  & 0.21  & 0.47  & 0.83  & 0.27  & 0.36  & 1     & 0.03  & 0.7   & 0.48 \\
    Var 23 & 0.99  & 0.55  & 0.23  & 0.72  & 0.55  & 0.16  & 0.49  & 0.73  & 0.57  & 0.78  & 0.37  & 0.05 \\
    Var 24 & 0.66  & 0.2   & 0.83  & 0.66  & 0.25  & 0.39  & 0.48  & 0.53  & 0.97  & 0.75  & 0.6   & 0.99 \\
    \end{tabular}}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Which, currently, looks as follows:
[image]

However, this looks very messy in my opinion. Would anyone be able to suggest me a different lay-out, or perhaps another way to make this table more readable? To me, the variables from sample 2 from e.g. the "count" column are to close to the variables from the "mean" column.

Comment: I woldn't use `\resizebox` for a table. It makes the font size inconsistent in your document. Try a landscape orientation and add some space between columns every other column.

Comment: Try centering the column labels `sample 1` and `sample 2` over their associated data. You can add more column space with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

 \begin{landscape}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\sisetup{table-format=1.2, table-number-alignment=center}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering\footnotesize
  \caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{@{\quad}l*{5}{SSp{4\tabcolsep}}SS}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Count} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Std. Dev.} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Min} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Median} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Max} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{5-6}\cmidrule{8-9}\cmidrule{11-12} \cmidrule{14-15}\cmidrule{17-18}
 &{Sample 1} & {Sample 2} && {Sample 1} & {Sample 2} && {Sample 1} & {Sample 2} && {Sample 1} & {Sample 2} && {Sample 1} & {Sample 2} && {Sample 1} &{Sample 2} \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multicolumn{18}{@{}l}{Panel A: Group 1} \\
\midrule
    Var 1  & 0.07 & 0.25 && 0.55 & 0.39 && 0.27 & 0.46 && 0.81 & 0.99 && 0.46 & 0.91 && 0.85 & 0.5 \\
    Var 2  & 0.49 & 0.74 && 0.79 & 0.11 && 0.23 & 0.34 && 0.22 & 0.37 && 0.08 & 0.14 && 0.58 & 0.64 \\
    Var 3  & 0.79 & 0.19 && 0.88 & 0.7  && 0.46 & 0.76 && 0.86 & 0.84 && 0.87 & 0.07 && 0.65 & 0.92 \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multicolumn{18}{@{}l}{Panel B: Group 2} \\
\midrule
    Var 4  & 0.52 & 0.91 && 0.68 & 0.17 && 0.44 & 0.77 && 0.85 & 0.54 && 0.51 & 0.38 && 0.29 & 0.1 \\
    Var 5  & 0.05 & 0.14 && 0.87 & 0.64 && 0.33 & 0.58 && 0.18 & 0.78 && 0.8  & 0.68 && 0.92 & 0.57 \\
    Var 6  & 0.81 & 0.81 && 0.61 & 0.42 && 0.25 & 0.54 && 0.68 & 0.7  && 0.34 & 0.11 && 0.49 & 0.11 \\
    Var 7  & 0.32 & 0.08 && 0.98 & 0.52 && 0.82 & 0.62 && 0.22 & 0.95 && 0.21 & 0.36 && 0.73 & 0.55 \\
    Var 8  & 0.63 & 0.58 && 0.86 & 0.39 && 0.81 & 0.79 && 0.19 & 0.89 && 0.12 & 0.7  && 0.32 & 0.25 \\
    Var 9  & 0.32 & 0.28 && 0.83 & 0.45 && 0.62 & 0.76 && 0.04 & 0.88 && 0.94 & 0.57 && 0.47 & 0.97 \\
    Var 10 & 0.71 & 0.65 && 0.78 & 0.69 && 0.47 & 0.89 && 0.5  & 0.68 && 0.8  & 0.38 && 0.62 & 0.71 \\
    Var 11 & 0.14 & 0.7  && 0.51 & 0.77 && 0.6  & 0.54 && 0.6  & 0.93 && 0.47 & 0.05 && 0.23 & 0.87 \\
    Var 12 & 0.33 & 0.02 && 0.4  & 0.39 && 0.35 & 0.65 && 0.03 & 0.45 && 0.77 & 0.59 && 0.61 & 0.6 \\
    Var 13 & 0.7  & 0.13 && 0.39 & 0.51 && 0.68 & 0.74 && 0.65 & 0.59 && 0.4  & 0.21 && 0.26 & 0.08 \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multicolumn{18}{@{}l}{Panel B: Group 2} \\
\midrule
    Var 14 & 0    & 0.15 && 0.55 & 0.96 && 0.59 & 0.6  && 0.54 & 0.81 && 0.49 & 0.6  && 0.79 & 0.5 \\
    Var 15 & 0.65 & 0.35 && 0.62 & 0.18 && 0.93 & 0.37 && 0.39 & 0.42 && 0.78 & 0.1  && 0.66 & 0.78 \\
    Var 16 & 0.64 & 0.43 && 0.07 & 0.36 && 0.91 & 0.18 && 0.41 & 0.59 && 0.18 & 1    && 0.85 & 0.25 \\
    Var 17 & 0.03 & 0.57 && 0.53 & 0.67 && 0.13 & 0.68 && 0.48 & 0.01 && 0.75 & 0.18 && 0.85 & 0.96 \\
    Var 18 & 0.12 & 0.72 && 0.61 & 0.1  && 0.61 & 0.66 && 0.65 & 0.37 && 0.42 & 0.8  && 0.4  & 0.46 \\
    Var 19 & 0.14 & 0.39 && 0.84 & 0.61 && 0.83 & 0.09 && 0.15 & 0.2  && 0.7  & 0.44 && 0.2  & 0.57 \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multicolumn{18}{@{}l}{Panel B: Group 2} \\
\midrule
    Var 20 & 0.7  & 0.05 && 0.94 & 0.94 && 0.7  & 0.21 && 0.01 & 0.06 && 0.44 & 0.99 && 0.71 & 0.86 \\
    Var 21 & 0.49 & 0.64 && 0.51 & 0.74 && 0.37 & 0.58 && 0.55 & 0.22 && 0.61 & 0.04 && 0.68 & 0.91 \\
    Var 22 & 0.83 & 0.37 && 0.67 & 0.21 && 0.47 & 0.83 && 0.27 & 0.36 && 1    & 0.03 && 0.7  & 0.48 \\
    Var 23 & 0.99 & 0.55 && 0.23 & 0.72 && 0.55 & 0.16 && 0.49 & 0.73 && 0.57 & 0.78 && 0.37 & 0.05 \\
    Var 24 & 0.66 & 0.2  && 0.83 & 0.66 && 0.25 & 0.39 && 0.48 & 0.53 && 0.97 & 0.75 && 0.6  & 0.99 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do like this suggestion as it looks very similar to the style that I put in my original question. One other question though: if I can't fit my caption on the same page as the able, is it best practice to split up my table in two parts and let it continue on another page, or should I scale down the size of the entire table?

Comment: Can you explain what you did with the tabular column declarations? I h have never seen anything like this but both you and Bernard did it.

Comment: @MennoVanDijk: Regarding your additional question: I'd say that one might have to decide case by case. If the caption is *not much* too long, you might be able to fit caption and table into the same page by adjusting or simply removing `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}`. Personally, I'd not reduce the font size further as `\footnotesize` already is quite small. If you decide to split your table onto two pages, you might want to use the `longtable` package. If you do so, please keep in mind that you will then have to remove the `table` environment and place the `\caption` differently.

Comment: @Bob: I'm not sure what exactly your comment refers to. In the column declarations `\begin{tabular}{@{\quad}l*{5}{SSp{4\tabcolsep}}SS}` `@{\quad}` adds the length `\quad` before every entry in the first column. This indentation is later removed for the `\multicolumn` entries via `@{}`. The piece `*{<number>}{<column specifier(s)}` lets one repeat the column specifiers in the second set of `{}` n times with n being the number in the first set of `{}`.

Comment: @Bob: `S` itself is a column specifier introduced by the `siunitx` package. `S` type columns allow you to horizontally center numbers with respect to their decimal separator. I hope this has answered your question.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks a bunch for you answer. Assumed that there wasn't a clear-cut solution to the issue, but glad to have that assumption reaffirmed. I will take a look at the suggestions you provided.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{array, booktabs, caption, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

 \begin{landscape}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\sisetup{table-format=1.2, table-number-alignment=center}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering\footnotesize
  \caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{SS@{\hskip 1.5em}}SS}
    \toprule            & \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hskip 1.5em}}{Count} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hskip 1.5em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hskip 1.5em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hskip 1.5em}}{Min} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hskip 1.5em}}{Median} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Max} \\
\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{1.5em}){2-3}\cmidrule(r{1.5em}){4-5}\cmidrule(r{1.5em}){6-7}\cmidrule(r{1.5em}){8-9} \cmidrule(r{1.5em}){10-11}\cmidrule(r{2pt}){12-13}
 &{Sample 1} & {Sample 2} & {Sample 1} & {Sample 2} & {Sample 1} & {Sample 2} & {Sample 1} & {Sample 2} & {Sample 1} & {Sample 2} & {Sample 1} &{Sample 2} \\
\addlinespace
 \rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{13}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Group 1}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Var 1} & 0.07 & 0.25 & 0.55 & 0.39 & 0.27 & 0.46 & 0.81 & 0.99 & 0.46 & 0.91 & 0.85 & 0.5 \\
    Var 2 & 0.49 & 0.74 & 0.79 & 0.11 & 0.23 & 0.34 & 0.22 & 0.37 & 0.08 & 0.14 & 0.58 & 0.64 \\
    Var 3 & 0.79 & 0.19 & 0.88 & 0.7 & 0.46 & 0.76 & 0.86 & 0.84 & 0.87 & 0.07 & 0.65 & 0.92 \\
\addlinespace
 \rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{13}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Group 2}} \\
    Var 4 & 0.52 & 0.91 & 0.68 & 0.17 & 0.44 & 0.77 & 0.85 & 0.54 & 0.51 & 0.38 & 0.29 & 0.1 \\
    Var 5 & 0.05 & 0.14 & 0.87 & 0.64 & 0.33 & 0.58 & 0.18 & 0.78 & 0.8 & 0.68 & 0.92 & 0.57 \\
    Var 6 & 0.81 & 0.81 & 0.61 & 0.42 & 0.25 & 0.54 & 0.68 & 0.7 & 0.34 & 0.11 & 0.49 & 0.11 \\
    Var 7 & 0.32 & 0.08 & 0.98 & 0.52 & 0.82 & 0.62 & 0.22 & 0.95 & 0.21 & 0.36 & 0.73 & 0.55 \\
    Var 8 & 0.63 & 0.58 & 0.86 & 0.39 & 0.81 & 0.79 & 0.19 & 0.89 & 0.12 & 0.7 & 0.32 & 0.25 \\
    Var 9 & 0.32 & 0.28 & 0.83 & 0.45 & 0.62 & 0.76 & 0.04 & 0.88 & 0.94 & 0.57 & 0.47 & 0.97 \\
    Var 10 & 0.71 & 0.65 & 0.78 & 0.69 & 0.47 & 0.89 & 0.5 & 0.68 & 0.8 & 0.38 & 0.62 & 0.71 \\
    Var 11 & 0.14 & 0.7 & 0.51 & 0.77 & 0.6 & 0.54 & 0.6 & 0.93 & 0.47 & 0.05 & 0.23 & 0.87 \\
    Var 12 & 0.33 & 0.02 & 0.4 & 0.39 & 0.35 & 0.65 & 0.03 & 0.45 & 0.77 & 0.59 & 0.61 & 0.6 \\
    Var 13 & 0.7 & 0.13 & 0.39 & 0.51 & 0.68 & 0.74 & 0.65 & 0.59 & 0.4 & 0.21 & 0.26 & 0.08 \\
\addlinespace
 \rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{13}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Group 2}} \\
    Var 14 & 0 & 0.15 & 0.55 & 0.96 & 0.59 & 0.6 & 0.54 & 0.81 & 0.49 & 0.6 & 0.79 & 0.5 \\
    Var 15 & 0.65 & 0.35 & 0.62 & 0.18 & 0.93 & 0.37 & 0.39 & 0.42 & 0.78 & 0.1 & 0.66 & 0.78 \\
    Var 16 & 0.64 & 0.43 & 0.07 & 0.36 & 0.91 & 0.18 & 0.41 & 0.59 & 0.18 & 1 & 0.85 & 0.25 \\
    Var 17 & 0.03 & 0.57 & 0.53 & 0.67 & 0.13 & 0.68 & 0.48 & 0.01 & 0.75 & 0.18 & 0.85 & 0.96 \\
    Var 18 & 0.12 & 0.72 & 0.61 & 0.1 & 0.61 & 0.66 & 0.65 & 0.37 & 0.42 & 0.8 & 0.4 & 0.46 \\
    Var 19 & 0.14 & 0.39 & 0.84 & 0.61 & 0.83 & 0.09 & 0.15 & 0.2 & 0.7 & 0.44 & 0.2 & 0.57 \\
\addlinespace
 \rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{13}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Group 2}} \\
    Var 20 & 0.7 & 0.05 & 0.94 & 0.94 & 0.7 & 0.21 & 0.01 & 0.06 & 0.44 & 0.99 & 0.71 & 0.86 \\
    Var 21 & 0.49 & 0.64 & 0.51 & 0.74 & 0.37 & 0.58 & 0.55 & 0.22 & 0.61 & 0.04 & 0.68 & 0.91 \\
    Var 22 & 0.83 & 0.37 & 0.67 & 0.21 & 0.47 & 0.83 & 0.27 & 0.36 & 1 & 0.03 & 0.7 & 0.48 \\
    Var 23 & 0.99 & 0.55 & 0.23 & 0.72 & 0.55 & 0.16 & 0.49 & 0.73 & 0.57 & 0.78 & 0.37 & 0.05 \\
    Var 24 & 0.66 & 0.2 & 0.83 & 0.66 & 0.25 & 0.39 & 0.48 & 0.53 & 0.97 & 0.75 & 0.6 & 0.99 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to correct the alignment of the multicolumn entries in the first row as they are shifted to the right.

Comment: @leandriis: Oh! yes. I hadn't noticed this. Done, thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm not too fond of the row colors myself, but the table layout is exactly as I wanted it. I do have one additional question you might be able to answer: if I can't fit my caption on the same page as the table, is it considered best practice to split up my table in two parts and let it continue on another page, or should I scale down the size of the entire table? Thanks.

Comment: Note I used only colour for panels, and the colour isn't really garish? This being said, I had another possibility; replace the \midrule above this panel title with a wimple `\addlinespace` and keep only the `\midrule` below  For your additional question, I suppose you mean the table is too long to fit on a single page? In this case, use `longtable` which will split it across pages automatically. I wouldn't use scaling down , as I explained in a commant for font size consistency and readability. The solution with longtable is by far better.